# Which new mp3 player to run old Python scripts

Tags: python, embedded, mp3

Which mp3/media player could I buy which will allow me to run an existing set of python scripts.

The existing scripts control xmms on linux: providing "next tracks" given data on ratings/last played/genre/how long since acquired/.... so that it all runs on a server upstairs somewhere, and I do not need to choose anything.

I'd like to use these scripts in the car, and I hope there is some media player that will let me change its playlist/current song from Python. Can you recommend such a machine ?

(I'd rather avoid the various types of iPod - they are a bit too "end-user focussed" for me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is to use an old iPod and [iPod Linux](http://ipodlinux.org/) and the [Python Port for iPod Linux](http://ciberjacobo.com/en/linux_on_ipod.html#python).
You'll use Podzilla's Media Player Daemon as the player and you'll have to figure out how to have your python scripts send control messages to it instead of xmms.

Answer (score 3):

The only possibility I'm aware of is to use [Rockbox](http://www.rockbox.org/), and then [port the Python interpreter](http://www.rockbox.org/mail/archive/rockbox-dev-archive-2008-08/0111.shtml) to it, or just port the functionality to some set of C programs, whichever suits you best. It might even come with the functionality you need already, so you'd just need to tweak some configuration files only.

> Rockbox is an open source firmware for
>   mp3 players, written from scratch. It
>   runs on a wide range of players:
>
> - Apple: 1st through 5.5th generation iPod, iPod Mini and 1st
>     generation iPod Nano (not the Shuffle, 2nd/3rd/4th gen Nano, Classic or Touch)
> - Archos: Jukebox 5000, 6000, Studio, Recorder, FM Recorder,
>     Recorder V2 and Ondio
> - Cowon: iAudio X5, X5V, X5L, M5, M5L, M3 and M3L
> - iriver: H100, H300 and H10 series
> - Olympus: M:Robe 100
> - SanDisk: Sansa c200, e200 and e200R series (not the v2 models)
> - Toshiba: Gigabeat X and F series (not the S series)

Comment: Just a heads-up: Rockbox runs (unstable, but supported) on Sansa Fuze (use it myself). Also on e200v2 (IINM) and other more "modern" models of the Sansas. (correct and full ;-) Details on the Rockbox site.